# Get suggestions for Occupation, College, etc. from Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, autosuggest

I'm writing a Facebook application, somewhat like a dating site (but not quite), and would like to allow my users to specify what kind of person they are looking for in terms of occupation, college, area, etc. I would like to make suggestions that match the suggestions Facebook provides when you change your own user profile details.

Of course, this could just be a text field, with some of my own custom AJAX suggestions, but is there not perhaps an API provided by Facebook for this sort of thing? If not an API, has anyone had success with using the same /ajax/typeahead/ script that facebook calls for this goal? How resistant is it to change?

**Edit**

I didn't mention any effort before - but that is basically because all my searches turned up nothing: I find no mention of this in the Facebook API, either the Graph API or the javascript SDK, and Google searches turned up nothing that I was looking for. Mostly people have only discussed the 'friend suggest' feature of Facebook in regards to any kind of 'suggestion', but not the AJAX-type autosuggest that I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for this function at Facebook API and deprecated Legacy is what you get: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/typeahead-input/

You have to look for something else than Facebook to implement it on your app.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Might you have any suggestions for a replacement?

Comment: You're welcome. I found this online: http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/auto-complete-type-ahead-dropdown-menu/ but I haven't tried it. Good luck. You can create another question asking for suggestions.

Comment: I meant more a replacement for the names of colleges, occupations, etc, than the type-ahead functionality ;) For that I usually use the jQuery plugin. But thanks!